# Google People API doesn't work in release mode android

Tags: android, google-signin, google-people-api

I am using google people API to sign in and retrieve person data of google account. Here's my code for fetching person data:

```
    protected Void getData(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
                profile.setEmail(acct.getEmail());
                profile.setName(acct.getDisplayName());

                GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                        context, Collections.singleton(Scopes.PROFILE)
                );
                credential.setSelectedAccount(new Account(acct.getEmail(), "com.google"));
                People service = new People.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                        .setApplicationName(context.getString(R.string.application_name))
                        .build();

                Person meProfile = null;
                try {
                    //here is the problem in release
                    meProfile = service.people().get("people/me").execute();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Logger.d(TAG, e);// it returns 404 Not Found
                    Logger.writeLog(LoginActivityNew.this, TAG, "e msg - " + e.getMessage());
                }

                if (meProfile != null) {
                    if (UtilCommon.isEmpty(profile.getName())) {
                        List<Name> names = meProfile.getNames();
                        if (names != null) {
                            for (Name name : names) {
                                if (!UtilCommon.isEmpty(name.getDisplayName())) {
                                    profile.setName(name.getDisplayName());
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    List<Birthday> birthdays = meProfile.getBirthdays();
                    if (birthdays != null && birthdays.size() > 0) {

                        for (Birthday bDay : birthdays) {
                            if (bDay == null || bDay.getDate() == null) continue;
                            Date date = bDay.getDate();
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date.getDay());
                            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, date.getMonth());
                            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, date.getYear());
                            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                            profile.setDOB(calendar.getTime());

                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    List<Gender> genders = meProfile.getGenders();
                    if (genders != null && genders.size() > 0) {

                        profile.setSex(Profile.SEX_NONE);
                        for (Gender genderObj : genders) {
                            if (genderObj == null || UtilCommon.isEmpty(genderObj.getValue())) continue;
                            String gender = genderObj.getValue();
                            if (gender.equals("male"))
                                profile.setSex(Profile.SEX_MALE);
                            else if (gender.equals("female"))
                                profile.setSex(Profile.SEX_FEMALE);
                            else if (gender.equals("unknown"))
                                profile.setSex(Profile.SEX_NONE);
                            else
                                profile.setSex(Profile.SEX_OTHERS);

                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    Logger.writeLog(LoginActivityNew.this, TAG, "name - " + profile.getName());
                    Logger.writeLog(LoginActivityNew.this, TAG, "gender - " + profile.getSex());
                    if (profile.getDOB() != null)
                        Logger.writeLog(LoginActivityNew.this, TAG, "dob - " + profile.getDOB());
                }
            }
```

Here in `meProfile = service.people().get("people/me").execute();` block an interesting thing is happening though Google sign in process is working fine.

> It works perfectly while in debug mode but not in release mode.

While using release mode this block returns an exception : `404 Not Found`

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

**I checked the google console project and provided valid SHA-1 certificate for debug and release keys.**

Anyone knows about this issue? I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate signed APK by **disabling proguard** if you have enabled it. You can do this by setting **minifyEnabled = false** in your build.gradle file.

If the issue is solved, then its a proguard related issue.

You can solve this buy including the people API related classes in proguard file using **keep class** attribute.

Comment: You are right bro. Didn't even think that it could be proguard related issue! Thanks for pointing out the problem. :)

Comment: glad that helped :)

Comment: Any chance you can share what proguard rules used to solve this.

Comment: -keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.**
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.location.**

Answer (score 0):

It is a proguard related issue.

To solve this just do  = **minifyEnabled false**

Go to build.gradle(app)

buildTypes {

```
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you saying that the app is not working with signed/exported apk?
If this is the case,
You need to add your signed SHA key to your Google app account.

https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing

You can find your signed SHA key like this -

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

Comment: I checked the google console project and provided valid SHA-1 certificate for debug and release keys.
You probably missed those lines. the issue is tracked now, it's related to proguard.